# Group an aggregated view by date without time

Tags: views, 8, entities

I would like to create a view that uses aggregation on an entity to display the count and the sum by date. But it should be grouped by date only without time even the original date value has time values. I.e.

Entity:
processedTime | amount | value | ...
01/01/2017 08:00:00 | 10 | 1 | ...
01/01/2017 08:18:10 | 10 | 1 | ... 
01/01/2017 10:00:00 | 10 | 1 | ... 
01/02/2017 08:00:00 | 10 | 1 | ... 
01/02/2017 09:30:00 | 10 | 1 | ... 
...

the view should output
01/01/2017 | 30 | 3 | ... 
01/02/2017 | 20 | 2 | ...

If I create a view with aggregation grouped by the date field, the view also evaluates the time and tries to group by the entire value of the date field. How can I group only by year, month and day without time?

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to the view for the date field you want to group by. In the filter config, set the date format to whatever level of granularity you want for the filter (in the image, it's by month), and tick *exclude from display*. Then you can group by this field.

[image: filter config]
[image: results]

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I want to use aggregation. In your example you are only grouping the items, but I want to group and to aggregate them (using count and sum).

Comment: I don't know that you can build this view completely within the Views UI. Having said that, it would be pretty easy to update your Twig templates to display the row count instead of the actual nodes.

Note: you may need the patch in https://www.drupal.org/node/2118743 to see what Twig templates Views is using.'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to aggregate by year with a date field with a Year only format (Y) and AVG as the aggregation method on the field. Grouping was on the NID which was hidden from view.